# Data type specifically for time in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

I just wanted to know is there any specific datatype for `time` or we have to use `Date` data type. Like i am creating an app where a chef will give total time the dish will take to be ready. Now i am creating a mongoose model.

```js
cookTime: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
```

is there any way by which i can  just store time like `10:50 pm` instead of `2021-06-22T21:30:34.736+00:00`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not for obvious reasons.

Types available out of the box are documented here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype

You can implement a custom type as described in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#customtypes

It's not quite clear what type you expect on nodejs level but you are limited to one of bson types on the database level https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/